# Create a UIScrollView that can be embedded into another view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, scroll, uipickerview

I'm trying to build a custom, reusable UIScrollView that can be added to multiple views. The scroll view is going to be a weight picker. For the life of me, I can't find a decent example for how to implement this neatly or cleanly.

I would love for someone to point me to an existing library or tutorial that shows me how to do this. I've hacked apart a few examples, but so far, nothing is very good or reusable. Please help!!

For what it's worth, I have an image that individual ticks for the weight. So I can select to the tenth of the number (e.g. 160.4). The image has the first tick bold and larger than the remaining 9. I'd like to have the weight/number centered over the large tick. I'll update the points to my label/datasource after scrolling stops.

*UPDATE* 
I need to make this. I have the custom font, background, and ticker image.

[image: weight picker]

Comment: cannot figure out what do you want to achieve. post an image

Comment: you want something like convert.app? or like the slot machine picker UI?

Comment: Why does a UIPickerView not work for you?

Comment: Pickerview won't work because it needs to look a specific way for client.

Comment: Have you done this creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were going to implement this, I would create a really wide image that had every weight on it I'd ever need - I would probably create this in code when the app started up. This image is then used as the contentView of your picker. You get all the scrolling features "for free", and you could even update the values shown in the other parts of the view during scrolling (or dragging.

The scrollView is just the area with the tick marks and weight numbers, and resides in a subview above the background, but below the centered vertical line that shows the actual weight.

EDIT: on second thought, forget the image. If you have the code to draw the image, you can do the drawing in a custom UIView. So you get the draw rect, you know the contentOffset, so you can draw just what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I would not do this through an `UIScrollView`. I think it would be more complex and you would certainly end up having issues when trying to add you custom picker into another scroll view.

What I would do is:

1. building the picker view by means of a series of CALayers, each one representing a "building block" of your picker view; see attached image:

   [image]
2. each building block would represent a specific value by mixing a UILabel (the text) and an image;
3. use a pan gesture recognizer, or alternatively define `touchesBegin/Moved/Ended` method to deal with panning;
4. when a pan is done, you displace the view content to the left or right according to the panning;
5. when panning, you also add new building blocks to the left or right end of the picker to account for empty areas that would be revealed by the displacement done at point 4.

I think that having a look at another kind of custom control source code would be of great help to you. You would not possibly find your custom picker already implemented, but could get some guidance. Have a look then at [cocoa controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I scoured cocoa controls but no luck finding a ready made control. I've looked all over the internet, the only good tutorials for UIScrollView are for pictures, zooming and scrolling.